# Clockwise Convention for measuring flux

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

The work done by a vector field $\vec F$ in moving along a trajectory C
$$\int_C \vec F \cdot d\vec r = \int_C \vec F \cdot \hat T ds$$

Where $\vec r$ is the position vector along C and $\hat T$ is the tangential vector along C

If I have to calculate the flux of the field across C then it is given by

$$\int \vec F \cdot \hat n ds$$

Where the convention used is $\hat n$ is $\hat T$ rotated clockwise.
What is the reason behind this clockwise convention?

Comment: I believe the convention is *anti* clockwise so that we follow the [right hand rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule#Curve_orientation_and_normal_vectors). No particular reason. Some convention is needed.